# Не работает сравнивание объектов

Tags: java, android

От сервера поступает ответ: 0, 1, 2 (со строками пытался и все равно без результата).

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                responseLogin = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                responseLogin = String.valueOf(responseLogin);

            }
```

Потом в зависимости от ответа выполняются действия

```
        switch (responseLogin) {
            case "0":
                //code
                break;
            case "1":
                //code
                break;
            case "2":
                //code
                break;
            default:
                done = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + responseLogin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
```

Значение есть, но почему-то не хочет сравнивать.

Comment: responseLogin должен быть интовым значением, и кейсить тоже надо по интам. Поддержка строк пока не везде добавлена. Если от строк не хотите уйти, то юзайте equals

Comment: пробелы, переводы строк?..

Comment: Пытался с инатми, `int temp = Integer.valueOf(responseLogin);switch (temp)`, выходит екзепшен `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0"`. Пробелов нету

Comment: при использовании `int` кавычки следует убрать

Comment: т.е. на самом деле от сервера приходит не `0`, а `"0"` (ноль в кавычках, три символа)? Выведите `responseLogin` в лог, да посмотрите, что внутри.

Comment: Я знаю, с кавычками android studio не пускает. Через дебаг увидел `"\uFEFF0"`, если поменять на "0" - все работает, как исправить это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в switch'е указать целочисленные варианты, а значение парсить из строки. (**Integer.parseInt(responseLogin)**)

```
String responseLogin = //значение...

responseLogin = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
responseLogin = String.valueOf(responseLogin); // зачем?

...

switch (Integer.parseInt(responseLogin)) {
   case 0:
        //code
        break;
   case 1:
        //code
        break;
   case 2:
        //code
        break;
   default:
        done = false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + responseLogin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Вот такая ошибка
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                              java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0"`
responseLogin = String.valueOf(responseLogin); добавил чтобы еще раз показать то что это строка

Comment: Возможно, кавычки - часть строки, передаваемой в метод.
Попробуйте вернуться к варианту с текстовыми кейсами, только сделайте варианты в виде "\"0\"", "\"1\"", "\"2\""...
Это для отладки.
Если заработает - просто очищайте строку от всех "не цифр".

Comment: Не работает :( В строке `"\uFEFF0"`, нужно как-то убрать `\uFEF`

Comment: Символ "\uFEFF" добавляется к файлам сохранённым в формате "UTF-8 with BOM", чтобы избежать этого, нужно использовать формат "UTF-8 without BOM". Если символ добавляется не к данным из файла или формы, а кданным, введённым руками, возможно, может помочь удаление всех проблемных символов из строки перед передачей в switch:
        char bom = '\uFEFF';
        String aaa = "" + bom + bom + bom;
        System.out.println(aaa.length());
        String replaceAll = aaa.replaceAll(bom + "", "");
        System.out.println(replaceAll.length());

Comment: Да, сохранил шаблон в кодировке `UTF-8 without BOM` и работает без среза

Comment: Да, можно не модифицировать строку, обращаясь через responseLogin.substring(1), как Вы сделали, к второму символу в строке. В случае, когда нужно будет справиться с большой строкой, надеюсь, Вам пригодится приём с replaceAll.

Answer (score 1):

Через дебаг увидел `"\uFEFF0"`. Надо было срезать строку те `switch(responseLogin.substring(1))`

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно,почему у вас не работает вышеуказанный код

```
String responseLogin = //значение строка

responseLogin = EntityUtils.toString(entity);//здесь объект как строка т 
//т е тип Строка


...
/*Здесь из тип Строка переводим в тип Целое,но с тем же значением.А потом 
 по типу Целое,по его значению выполняем ту или иную ветку
 */
switch (Integer.parseInt(responseLogin)) {
case 0:
    //code
    break;
case 1:
    //code
    break;
case 2:
    //code
    break;
default:
    done = false;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + responseLogin, 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
    break;
    }
```

Однозначно надо работать с тип Целое.Если в responseLogin приходит именно "0" т е символ кавычка,символ 0,символ кавычка,то надо substing-ом очисть до символ 0.